# expected the response to have status code :unprocessable_entity (422) but it was :forbidden (403)

Tags: rspec, multi-tenant

I was trying to do tenant enforcement for product model. but in request spec for update it shows the following error:
expected the response to have status code :unprocessable_entity (422) but it was :forbidden (403).

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :validate_tenant, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @products=Product.where(tenant_id: current_context.tenant_id).all

    render json: @products
  end

  def show
    render json:@product
  end

  def create
    @product= Product.create(product_params)
    if @product.save
      render json:@product, status: :created
    else
      render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

  end

  def update
    if @product.update(product_params)
      render json: @product
    else
      render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end

  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
  end

  private
  def set_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def validate_tenant
    if @product and !@product.tenant_id.eql?(current_context.tenant_id)
      raise ApiM8::Exceptions::TenantMismatch.new
    end
    if @product and product_params.include?(:tenant_id) and !@product.tenant_id.eql?(product_params[:tenant_id])
      raise ApiM8::Exceptions::TenantMismatch.new
    end
  end

  def product_params
    json_api_params(Product,[:visible, :type, :tenant_id]).fetch(:attributes,{})
  end

end



require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ProductsController, :type => :controller do
  before {
    controller_stub_token_authentication
  }

  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  let(:context) {
    OpenStruct.new(
        tenant_id: SecureRandom.uuid
    )
  }

  before {
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_context).and_return(context)
  }

  describe "GET index" do
    let!(:products){ create_list :product, rand(2..10), tenant_id: context.tenant_id  }
    it "assigns all products as @products" do
      get :index, parrams:{}, session:valid_session
      expect(assigns(:products)).to eq(products)
    end
  end

  describe "GET show" do
    let!(:product) { create :product ,tenant_id: context.tenant_id }
    it "assigns the requested product as @product" do
      get :show, params:{:id => product.to_param}, session:valid_session
      expect(assigns(:product)).to eq(product)
    end
  end

  describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Product" do
        expect {
          post :create, params: json_api_params(Product, attributes_for(:product)), session:valid_session
        }.to change(Product, :count).by(1)
      end

      it "assigns a newly created product as @product" do
        post :create,params: json_api_params(Product, attributes_for(:product)), session:valid_session
        expect(assigns(:product)).to be_a(Product)
        expect(assigns(:product)).to be_persisted
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns a newly created but unsaved product as @product" do
        post :create, params: json_api_params(Product, attributes_for(:product).update(tenant_id: nil)),session: valid_session
        expect(assigns(:product)).to be_a_new(Product)
      end
    end
  end


  describe "PUT update" do
    let!(:product) { create :product, tenant_id: context.tenant_id}
    let(:new_attributes) {
      attributes_for(:product).update(tenant_id: context.tenant_id)
    }
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "updates the requested product" do
        put :update,params: {:id => product.to_param}.update(json_api_params(Product,new_attributes)), session:valid_session
        product.reload
        new_attributes.each do |attr, val|
          expect(product.send(attr)).to eq(val)
        end
      end

      it "assigns the requested product as @product" do
        put :update,params: {:id => product.to_param}.update(json_api_params(Product,new_attributes)), session:valid_session
        expect(assigns(:product)).to eq(product)
      end
    end

    describe "with invalid params" do
      it "assigns the product as @product" do
        put :update,params: {:id => product.to_param}.update(
            json_api_params(Product,new_attributes.update(tenant_id: nil))),session: valid_session
        expect(assigns(:product)).to eq(product)
      end

    end
  end

  describe "DELETE destroy" do
    let!(:product){ create :product,tenant_id: context.tenant_id  }
    it "destroys the requested product" do
      expect {
        delete :destroy,params: {:id => product.to_param}, session:valid_session
      }.to change(Product, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end

end




require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Products", :type => :request do
  before {
    controller_instance_stub_token_authentication(ProductsController)
  }

  let(:headers) {
    {}.merge(token_authentication).merge(json_api_headers)
  }


  let(:context) {
    OpenStruct.new(
        tenant_id: SecureRandom.uuid
    )
  }

  before {
    allow_any_instance_of(ProductsController).to receive(:current_context).and_return(context)
  }


  describe 'GET /products' do
    let!(:products) { create_list :product, rand(5..10),tenant_id: context.tenant_id }

    it 'responds with :ok' do
      get products_path, headers: headers, as: :json
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end

    it 'responds with a list' do
      get products_path, headers: headers, as: :json
      expect(json_api_response).to be_a(Array)
    end

    it 'responds with a correct list' do
      get products_path, headers: headers, as: :json
      expect(json_api_response.size).to eq(products.count)
      expect(products.map(&:id)).to include(json_api_response.first['id'])
      expect(json_api_response.first['attributes']).to include('visible', 'url')
    end

  end

  describe 'GET /products/:id' do
    let!(:product) { create :product, tenant_id: context.tenant_id }

    describe 'for existing item' do
      it 'is a valid JSON API response' do
        get product_path(product), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(response.body).to be_json_api_response_for(Product)
      end
      it 'responds with the correct item' do
        get product_path(product), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(json_api_response['id']).to eq(product.id.to_s)
      end

      it 'responds with the correct information' do
        get product_path(product), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(json_api_response['attributes']).to include('visible', 'url')
      end

      it 'responds with :ok' do
        get product_path(product), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
      end
    end

    describe 'for missing item' do
      it 'responds with :not_found' do
        get product_path(-1000), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:not_found)
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'POST /products' do
   # let!(:product) { create :product, tenant_id: context.tenant_id}

    describe 'with valid params' do
      it 'responds with :created' do
        _attrs = attributes_for(:product).slice(:visible, :tenant_id)
        post products_path, params: json_api_params(Product, _attrs), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
      end
    end

    describe 'with invalid params' do
      it 'responds with :unprocessable_entity' do
        post products_path, params: json_api_params(Product, { tenant_id: nil }), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'PUT /products/:id' do
    let!(:product) { create :product, tenant_id: context.tenant_id}
    let(:new_attributes) { {tenant_id: context.tenant_id} }
    #let(:new_attributes) { attributes_for(:product).update(tenant_id: context.tenant_id)}

    describe 'with valid params' do

      it 'updates the requested product' do
        put product_path(product), params: json_api_params(Product, new_attributes), headers: headers, as: :json
        product.reload
        expect(product.attributes.with_indifferent_access).to include(new_attributes)
      end

      it 'responds with :ok' do
        put product_path(product), params: json_api_params(Product, new_attributes), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
      end
    end

    describe 'with invalid params' do
        it 'responds with :unprocessable_entity' do
          #skip('no fields to check this spec, :tenant is validated before AR::update')
          put product_path(product), params: json_api_params(Product, { tenant_id:nil }), headers: headers, as: :json
          expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        end

      it 'responds with :forbidden for different :tenant' do
        put product_path(product), params: json_api_params(Product, { tenant_id: SecureRandom.uuid }), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:forbidden)
      end
    end

    describe 'with missing item' do
      it 'responds with :not_found' do
        put product_path(-1000), params: json_api_params(Product, new_attributes), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:not_found)
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'DELETE /products/:id' do
    let!(:product) { create :product, tenant_id: context.tenant_id }

    it 'for existing item, responds with :no_content' do
      delete product_path(product), headers: headers, as: :json
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:no_content)
    end
    it 'for missing item, responds with :not_found' do
      delete product_path(-1000), headers: headers, as: :json
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:not_found)
    end
    context 'responds with :forbidden' do
      it 'for different :tenant' do
        product.update(tenant_id: SecureRandom.uuid)
        delete product_path(product), headers: headers, as: :json
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:forbidden)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your test also?

Comment: In request spec I used skip() method to over come the error. like                   it  ' responds with :unprocessable_entity' do
        skip('no fields to check this spec,  :tenant are validated before AR::update')
      end